# How to create MUL key in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, key

I'm trying to provide support of sqlite3 to an already existing python application which uses MySQL. There is a query in MySQL which I want to convert in sqlite3 for creating a table which makes two of its columns as MUL key.

In MySQL we can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id BIGINT(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    group_id INTEGER, 
    feat VARCHAR(36), 
    KEY \`field\` (\`group_id\`), 
    KEY \`feature\` (\`feat\`)
)
```

How can I write the same query in sqlite3?
How can I create a multiple key 'MUL' in sqlite3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have 3 ways. 2 options if the MUL should be unique and another if uniqueness isn't required.

e.g. :-

```
/* Unique constraint and therefore an auto-created index */
CREATE TABLE messages1 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    group_id INTEGER, feat TEXT, 
    UNIQUE(group_id, feat)
);

/* Unique constraint not required and therefore just an index */
CREATE TABLE messages2 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    group_id INTEGER, feat TEXT 
);
CREATE INDEX messages_idx01 ON messages2 (group_id,feat);

/* A specifically named UNIQUE index */
CREATE TABLE messages3 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    group_id INTEGER, feat TEXT 
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX messages_idx02 ON messages3 (group_id,feat);
```

- Note the derived column types have been used.

  - That is column types (type affinity) are quite different in SQLite, they are more flexible and only an indication of the type of data stored. see [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
  - e.g. BIGINT(16) has a derived column type of INTEGER, so INTEGER has been used.
  - Also note that AUTOINCREMENT has been used, however you should read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), as it would very likely not be required and that it introduces inefficiencies/overheads.